# How do I show my new footer to display only on the home page?

Tags: php, wordpress

In my Wordpress Theme, I have a "default" footer I use for every page, but I created a new footer I want to display only on the home page.

How do I hide the old footer and display my new footer on the home page?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could solve this, and none are more or less correct than the others. The way I would suggest is this;

Assuming you don't have it already, create **front-page.php** template and copy the content of **page.php** into it (if that's the template you're using).

Replace `get_footer()` at the end of **front-page.php** with `get_footer('home')` (assuming your new footer is called 'home-footer.php' (see [the docs](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) for more on that one)

As an alternatively, you could simply edit **page.php** and replace `get_footer()` with something like:

```
if(is_front_page()) { //check if current page is the home page
    get_footer('home');
} else {
    get_footer();
}
```

Which utilises the `is_front_page` conditional. (see [conditional](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/references/list-of-conditional-tags/) tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom template for homepage and call the new footer from that template using the function `get_footer( $name )`, here `$name` is the name of the new footer that you have created. Then select the homepage template from dashboard home page.

Answer (score 0):

Open the header.php
Edit the `<body>` tag and make it `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`

now in your homepage your body tag will render `<body class="home">`

then write css like:

```
body.home footer {
    display: none;
}
```

add new footer in your homepage content